# how to convert string to time formatted in flutter

Tags: date, datetime, flutter

I have data from database "192624". how I can change the String format in flutter become time formatted. example `"192624" become to "19:26:24"`. I try using intl packages is not my hope result.

this my code

```
DateTime inputDate = inputDate;
    String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(inputDate);
```

in above is not working
I want result convert data("192624") to become "19:26:24". data time from database.

Comment: postingDate = "data from database"; String formattedTime = DateFormat.Hms().format(postingDate); is not working. I want result convert data("192624") to become "19:26:24".

Comment: "192624"
          .replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r".{2}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)}:")

Comment: Do you want the output string to be in datetime format for String format.

Comment: it working. this output result 19:26:24: how to remove symbol " :  " after number 4

Comment: @nasipadang I write a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out this a answer  :

```
String time;
// call this upper value globally 
  String x = "192624";
  print(x.length);
  x = x.substring(0, 2) + ":" + x.substring(2, 4)+":"+x.substring(4,x.length);
  time =x;
  print(x);
```

just globally declare the string and then assign the local String to global then call it in the ui

Answer (score 2):

use this method

```
String a() {
var a = "192624".replaceAllMapped(
    RegExp(r".{2}"), (match) => "${match.group(0)}:");
var index = a.lastIndexOf(":");
a = a.substring(0,index);
return a;
}
```

Comment: call a inside widget Text(a)